# Running a Java app which is compiled on 1.7 JDK with JRE 11 using JAva FX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I have an executablle Jar which is compiled with JDK 1.7.

My computer has java version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16 LTS,Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS, mixed mode)

I am on ubuntu.

When I run the jar using java -jar run.jar I get a message

Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

I have downloaded the OpenFX11 - can this work with this? https://openjfx.io/

Or is there a different JavaFx available?

what will be the syntax for the command to make the runtime use the downloaded javafx lib, classpath doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX 11 is no longer bundled with JDK , it builds on top of JDK 11 and is a standalone component.

Just see this video on how to integrate them [youtube.com/watch?v=qn2tbftFjno](http://video%20link) .

You need to download the stand-alone JavaFx here >>>> [gluonhq.com/products/javafx](http://link) .

Answer (score 0):

This approach will probably not work at all. If all you have is an executable jar file created with the ancient java 1.7 then this will not be binary compatible anymore with the current JavaFX. Depending on what features are used in your jar, you will most likely stumble over certain API changes which will blow up your code.

Comment: Its not my code, I have no access to source. I am trying to execute an application, Do I need to downgrade to Java 1.7 to run this jar

Comment: Java 1.8 might still work but you wil have to give it a try yourself.